# PostgreSQL 8.4: How to tell if a procedural language is installed or not?

Tags: postgresql, functions, plpgsql, postgresql-8.4, postgresql-extensions

I have a setup program that requires plpgsql to install stored procedures in a PostgreSQL 8.4 database. I need to make sure the language is installed or the app will fail. I don't want to drop the language and re-add it, as that could screw some other things up.

Is there a way to install the language "gently"?
`CREATE LANGUAGE IF NOT EXISTS` does not appear to be valid.

Comment: http://timmurphy.org/2011/08/27/create-language-if-it-doesnt-exist-in-postgresql/  or this: http://andreas.scherbaum.la/blog/archives/346-create-language-if-not-exist.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PostgreSQL **9.0** and later, PL/pgSQL is pre-installed by default.
Version 9.0 also introduced [`CREATE OR REPLACE LANGUAGE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-createlanguage.html):

> `CREATE OR REPLACE LANGUAGE` will either create a new language, or
>   replace an existing definition. If the language already exists, its
>   parameters are updated according to the values specified or taken from
>   `pg_pltemplate` ...

To avoid raising an exception on **older versions** you can check the catalog table [`pg_language`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-language.html). I quote the [manual once more](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createlanguage.html):

> The system catalog pg_language [...] records information
>   about the currently installed languages.

```
SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   pg_language
  WHERE  lanname = 'plpgsql');
```

Or use the client application [`createlang`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-createlang.html), which has an option to check for existing languages:

```
createlang -l [connection parameters]
```